# In ArangoDB AQL is there anything like mysqli_real_escape_string?

Tags: php, arangodb, aql, arangodb-php

There are obvious security reasons why using `mysqli_real_escape_string` in MySQL.

Right now I am sending queries via PHP to ArangoDB. The AQL queries also contain variables. In MySQL I have learned to prepare them with `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

Is there anything similar in Arango AQL to prepare variables before using them in queries?
Unfortunately I haven't found anything like that in the Arango documentation. Any advice very welcome.